# Confusion with analysis of hashing with chaining

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, hash-tables

I was attending a class on analysis of hash tables implemented using chaining, and the professor said that:

> In a hash table in which collisions are resolved by
>   chaining, an search (successful or unsuccessful) takes average-case time θ(1 + α),
>   under the assumption of simple uniform hashing.

and

> The worst-case time for searching is θ(n) plus the time to
>   compute the hash function.

These are quoted from out textbook, ITA. Here α is the load factor, which is equal to n/m where n is the total number of elements to be inserted to the hash table and m is the size of the hash table (which is a constant for each implementation).

My confusion arises from the thinking that

> θ(1 + α) = θ(α) = θ(n/m) = θ(n)

So I claimed that θ(1 + α) = θ(n), ie the average case and worst case time complexities are the same and the professor disagrees with me.

She asked me to find out by myself why I am wrong. I did some brainstorming and the only deduction I can make is that either I am wrong in assuming that m is a constant or asymptotic notations can't be used to compare between worst-case and average-case running time in this case. Please help me find what is wrong here. Also  I don't understand why θ(1 + α) is not written simply as θ(α) and also why the professor insists on the value of α being less than, equal to, or greater than 1

Answer (score 4):

The reason that we are using $\Theta(1+\alpha)$ rather than $\Theta(\alpha)$ is that $\alpha$ could be very small. Imagine for example that the hidden constant in both $\Theta$s is one, and that $\alpha=0.000001$. There is a large difference between $1.000001$ and $0.000001$.

Regarding your wrong deduction, note that the first paragraph mentions *average* case and the second *worst* case. It's true that the average case is at most the worst case, but not the other way around.

Comment: So am I wrong is saying that the time complexities of both average case and worst case are both  θ(n)?

Comment: Yes, that's incorrect in general. Your professor was right when she suggested you find out yourself why. I tried to give you a hint in my answer.

Comment: Here n is the input size and m is a constant. If generally θ(kn) = θ(n) where k is a constant, then why is  θ(1/m * n) ≠ θ(n) where 1/m is a constant.

Comment: We don't think of $m$ as constant, since it's not really constant. Different instances of the data structure can have widely different $m$. It's as if you would say that the space is $O(1)$ rather than $\Theta(m)$.

Comment: What do you call such non-constant terms? Each instance of the data structure has different but constant m. So when we compute the running time, should we account for such constants? Why?

Comment: Whenever you run an algorithm on a particular input, all the parameters are fixed. That doesn't mean that when we compute the asymptotic performance of an algorithm we assume that they are constant. In other words, $m$ and $n$ are both values of the same "type". You can call them *parameters*, but that's not a particularly good term.

Answer (score 0):

O(1+α) is only equal to O(α) when α becomes much greater than 1 and for hash tables that is usually not the case. For a chaining hash table it would typically be around 1 and for an open addressing hash table it would be less than or equal to 1.
If α much greater than 1 we would be calling it a hash table any more but rather a bunch of lists that indeed will have an asymptotic complexity of O(n).